# Postgresql v10.1 - How to fix ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, amazon-dms

I'm not sure how this happened to this table but  have an issue with `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` trying to use AWS's DMS service to move a postgres v10.1 DB to RDS v10

The table looks like

```
# \d+ public.brokered_carriers
                                                                  Table "public.brokered_carriers"
         Column         |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                    | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                     | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('brokered_carriers_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 name                   | character varying           |           |          |                                               | extended |              |
 code                   | character varying           |           |          |                                               | extended |              |
 external_id            | character varying           |           |          |                                               | extended |              |
 mc_number              | character varying           |           |          |                                               | extended |              |
 dot_number             | character varying           |           |          |                                               | extended |              |
 phone_1                | character varying           |           |          |                                               | extended |              |
 phone_2                | character varying           |           |          |                                               | extended |              |
 tms_payment_address_id | integer                     |           |          |                                               | plain    |              |
 account_id             | integer                     |           | not null |                                               | plain    |              |
 data                   | jsonb                       |           |          | '{}'::jsonb                                   | extended |              |
 created_at             | timestamp without time zone |           |          |                                               | plain    |              |
 updated_at             | timestamp without time zone |           |          |                                               | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "brokered_carriers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_brokered_carriers_on_account_id_and_external_id" UNIQUE, btree (account_id, external_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_39675fc9f0" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
```

The DMS error is

> dms-tasks-company dms-task-2JVAOJI7TQAZSPCVDXDTYBA5YE 2019-10-18T17:59:37 [TARGET_LOAD     ]I:  Table 'public'.'brokered_carriers' has Non-Optimized Full LOB Support  (odbc_endpoint_imp.c:4708)
>
> dms-tasks-company dms-task-2JVAOJI7TQAZSPCVDXDTYBA5YE 2019-10-18T17:59:37 [TARGET_LOAD     ]E:  RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 23505 NativeError: 1 Message: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_brokered_carriers_on_account_id_and_external_id"; Error while executing the query [1022510]  (ar_odbc_stmt.c:2639)
>
> dms-tasks-company dms-task-2JVAOJI7TQAZSPCVDXDTYBA5YE 2019-10-18T17:59:37 [SOURCE_UNLOAD   ]I:  Unload finished for table 'public'.'brokered_carriers' (Id = 18). 19163 rows sent.  (streamcomponent.c:3473)

Any idea how to fix this and fix the constraint?

Comment: That's just a primary key collision. Try again with an `id` that doesn't yet exist in the table.

Comment: this is migration tool so I don't have control over changing inserts.. looking for a way to find the collision

Comment: The error message tells you that the constraint "index_brokered_carriers_on_account_id_and_external_id" is violated, so all you need to do is find rows with duplicate values in those two columns.